# Duplication notice doesn't contain the duplicated question

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, post-notice

Question in question: [Specifying thickness of lines in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12377377/3416774)

> [image]

Comment: That's a _very_ old dupe closure from the time before duplicates could properly be linked. The target was edited into the question back then.